# The order in which functions are executed is asynchronous (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
Javascript Code:

var express    = require("express");
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var app = express();

    var speechwindow,id,intent_id,Intent_response;

function getResults(output,url_id,intent_num,callback) {
    // The result for speech window
            var speech = output;
            console.log(output);

    // The result for the plotly embed urls
            var url = 'https://plot.ly/~me/'+url_id+'/'; 
            console.log(url);
            var img = 'https://plot.ly/~me/'+url_id+'.png';
            console.log(img);
            var data = 'me:'+url_id;
            console.log(data);

    // The result for sample utterances
            var choose = intent_num;
            var Intent= ['RepeatIntent','CustomOptionIntent','HelpIntent','FinishIntent','OpenEndedOptionTwoIntent','OpenEndedOptionOneIntent','ChangeSetpointIntent','ChoiceIntent'];
            if (Intent[choose] === 'RepeatIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['repeat the options','can you repeat the options','tell me the options','state the options'];
            }
            else if (Intent[choose] === 'CustomOptionIntent') {
                 var Intent_response = ['set the {setpointType} set point to {setPointValue} degree celsius','set the {setpointType} at {setPointValue} degree celsius','{setpointType} is {setPointValue} degrees'];   
            }
            else if (Intent[choose] === 'HelpIntent'){
                 var Intent_response = ['what questions can I ask','what are various options which I can know about from you','help me','what commands can I say'];
            }
            else if (Intent[choose] === 'FinishIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['exit','quit','bye','leave'];
            }
            else if (Intent[choose]=== 'OpenEndedOptionTwoIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['I want to select my own strategy','I want to choose my own strategy','I want to form my custom strategy','I want to form my own strategy'];
            }
            else if (Intent[choose] === 'OpenEndedOptionOneIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['which is the best strategy to go with','suggest me the best strategy','provide me with best solution for power consumption','suggest me most efficient power solution'];
            }
            else if(Intent[choose] === 'ChangeSetpointIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['what happens if I change {setpointType} to {setPointValue} percent','what happens if I change {setpointType} to {setPointValue} degrees','what will happen if I change the {setpointType} to {setPointValue} degree celsius','I want to change {setpointType} to {setPointValue} degree celsius'];
            }
            else if (Intent[choose] === 'ChoiceIntent'){
                var Intent_response = ['select option {optionNumber}','select option number {optionNumber}','choose option {optionNumber}'];
            }
            console.log(Intent_response);
            var results = [speech,url,img,data,Intent_response];
}
function generateResponse(req, res) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'user',
          password : 'password',
          database : 'mydatabase'
        });
       connection.connect(function(err){
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");
        } else {
            console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");
        }
        });
       connection.query('SELECT * FROM `RTES` ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(!err){
            var speechwindow = rows[0].ALEXA;
            console.log(speechwindow);
            var id = rows[0].URL_ID;
            console.log(id);
            var intent_id = rows[0].INTENT_NUM;
            console.log(intent_id);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Error');}
    });
            getResults(speechwindow,id,intent_id,function(results) {
                connection.end();
                res.render('dashboard.ejs', {results: results});
            });
}

exports.displayResponse = function(req, res){
    generateResponse(req, res);
};
```

Output Window:

```
undefined
https://plot.ly/~me/undefined/
https://plot.ly/~me/undefined.png
me:undefined
undefined
Database is connected ...


As per my forecast, the best strategy has a lighting of 60 percent, zone temperature of 26 degree celsius, and chilled water temperature of 9 degree celsius, and it leads to a power consumption of 1.23 mega watts. You have a curtailment of 268.00 killo watts than the baseline consumption. In order to continue, you may say state the options or you may say exit if you want to quit.
113
7
```

I want my database to be connected and the query to be executed before the getResults function is executed. In the output window, the getResult function is executed before the generateResponse function due to which everything is undefined. I tried to put the getResult function as a callback of generateResponse function but I got the same output.
I checked several question but failed to get a definite answer. I am unsure what to change so that the function runs in a synchoronous fashion. I am new to javascript and maybe my understanding of asynchoronous execution is limited and hence i am unable to resolve this error.

Comment: What does it mean *The order in which functions are executed is asynchronous*? The order is neither synchronous nor asynchronous.

Comment: @skypjack I believe the question is why the callbacks are not executing in the expected order.

Comment: Could you please edit your question title into a question title? It's also hard to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: It's always a good idea to minimize the code you're posting. Remove everything that isn't needed to reproduce the problem. Also helps if the code is properly indented. More people will read it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `getResults` call within the `connection.query()` callback, not after it.